Dehn Twist Actions on Surface Homology
The mapping class group of a surface $\Sigma_g$ acts on $H_1(\Sigma_g, \mathbb{Z})$. Below, I drew some curves $a_1, b_1, a_3, a_3 - a_1$ representing homology classes. I'm trying to understand the actions of the Dehn twists $T_{a_3 - a_1}$ and $T_{a_3 + a_1}$ on $b_1$. My questions are:

$b_1$ intersects the curve $a_3 - a_1$ once, so $T_{a_3 - a_1}(b_1) = b_1 + a_3 - a_1$. This is different from $T_{a_3}T_{a_1}^{-1}(b_1) = b_1 - a_1$. I would expect $T_{a_3 - a_1} = T_{a_3}T_{a_1}^{-1}$... why are these not equal, and why was I wrong to expect these mapping classes to act the same?
What does a curve representing $a_1 + a_3 \in H_1(\Sigma_g, \mathbb{Z})$ look like?



Nice, illustrative question and answer....

First a minor correction: the blue oriented curve is $a_1-a_3$, not $a_3-a_1$; you can check this with the right hand rule applied to the pair of pants bounded by the blue curve and the two red curves. But this can be fixed by reversing the arrow on the blue curve.
Anyway, while you did not give any reason for expecting the equation $T_{a_3-a_1} = T_{a_3} T_{a_1}^{-1}$ to hold, perhaps you were thinking that this equation is an instance of some kind of homomorphism, where the function $T$, which assigns to each homology class of oriented simple closed curves $a$ the Dehn twist $T_a$, extends to a homomorphism
$$T : H_1(\Sigma_g,\mathbb Z) \mapsto MCG(\Sigma_g)
$$
Well, no such homomorphism exists, and your calculation proves it.
But here's a simpler reason that no such homomorphism exists. Consider any oriented simple closed curve $d$ which separates the surface. For example, the regular neighborhood of $a_1 \cup b_1$ has boundary curve $d$ which can be drawn on your surface so as to separate the "left hole" from the "middle and right holes", and in homotopy we have $d=a_1b_1a_1^{-1}b_1^{-1}$, so in homology $d=0$. But $T_d$ certainly is not the identity mapping class. In fact any separating oriented simple closed curve $d$ represents the trivial element of homology, but $T_d$ is never the identity mapping class (assuming that $d$ is essential, i.e.  $d$ does not bound a disc).
As for your second question, although the homology class $a_1 + a_3$ is not represented by any simple closed curve, if you connect a point of $a_1$ to a point of $a_3$ by a path $\gamma$ then $a_1+a_3$ it is represented by the closed curve $a_1 \gamma a_3 \bar\gamma$ which is homotopic to a nonsimple closed curve with self intersection number $1$. And this emphasizes a point which, perhaps, is why you asked about $a_1+a_3$. Note that there is no Dehn twist assigned to curves with self intersection $1$. And as said the Dehn twist assigned to each simple closed curve does not induce a homomorphism assigning a mapping class to each homology class. But also there is no natural way at all to pick a Dehn twist assigned to an arbitrary homology class (outside of just picking a random, meaningless assignment): the identity homology class has too many simple closed curves representing it; some homology classes have no simple closed representatives at all.
